# JPA diagram: other attributes are not displayed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

experts,

I'm trying to make a test project using JPA.
The problem is that when I add attributes to an Entity (Person on the screenshot), those attributes are not shown on the diagram, so I can't even rename them (see screenshot). A quick search didn't help.

[image]

How do I solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with JPA. It has everything to do with your UML tool, that, I guess, is some Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Start by tagging your question correctly. By tagging it with jpa, you'll get people, like me, who know about JPA. Not people who know about Eclipse UML plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)'s help.

I've installed the [JPA Diagram Editor](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jpa-diagram-editor) from Eclipse market (Eclipse: ***Help->Eclipse Marketplace...***), reopened the diagram view and it helped.

[image]